# About eigenspace of a dynamic system in lemma 5.2 of Elements of Applied Bifurcation Theory. Kuznetsov

Tags: linear-algebra, dynamical-systems

I need help to prove a lemma from this document

[https://www.ma.imperial.ac.uk/~dturaev/kuznetsov.pdf](https://www.ma.imperial.ac.uk/%7Edturaev/kuznetsov.pdf)

Problem 3, section 5. Prove Lemma 5.2, that says so

Suppose we have a dynamic system in continuous time:

$$\dot{x} = Ax + F(x), \quad x\in \mathbb{R}^{n}$$

where $F(x) = O(\left\| x \right\|^{2})$ is a smooth function.

$A$ has a simple zero eigenvalue $\lambda_{1} = 0$, and the corresponding critical eigenspace $T^{c}$ is one dimensional and spanned by an eigenvector $q\in \mathbb{R}^{n}$ such that $Aq = 0$. Let $p\in \mathbb{R}^{n}$ be the adjoint eigenvector, that is, $A^{T}p = 0$, where $A^{T}$ is the transposed matrix

**Lemma 5.2: Let $T^{su}$ denote $(n-1)$ dimensional linear eigenspace of $A$ corresponding to all eigenvalues other than $0$. Then $y\in T^{su}$ if and only if $\langle p,y \rangle = 0$**.

in the text (page 172) they mention that it can be proved with the "Fredholm Alternative Theorem" but the truth is not entirely clear to me how to prove it.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** By the Fredholm alternative (= image of $A$ coincides with the orthogonal complement of the kernel of $A^T$) it suffices to show that the stable-unstable space of $A$ coincides with the image of $A$. Note that the kernel of $A^T$ is one dimensional and is spanned by $p$.

If $v$ is in the stable-unstable space of $A$, then it can be written as a linear combination of (generalized) eigenvectors $v^\lambda$ associated to nonzero eigenvalues $\lambda$ of $A$. Since $Av^\lambda=\lambda v^\lambda$ we have $v^\lambda=\frac{1}{\lambda}Av^\lambda$.

Conversely, any $v$ can be split into a center and stable-unstable part $v=v^c+v^{su}$ and $Av= Av^{su}= \bigoplus_{\lambda\neq0} \lambda v^\lambda$, and so $Av$ is in the stable-unstable space of $A$.